# TYPE_KEYGUARD keep fullscreen mode after placing a call

Tags: android, window, overriding, statusbar

We´re going to give devices to clients and they need to be able to call us with a button. In my fullscreen `Activity` I have a button that calls the helpdesk phonenumber, so `onClick()` it does the following:

```
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, mContext.getString(R.string.couldntcall), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

When the dialer closes, suddenly the titlebar stays visible, I´m guessing it has something to do with overriding the `HOME` button:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow()
{  //HOMEBUTTON
    if(OnLockMode())
    {   
        this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
          super.onAttachedToWindow();
    }
    else
    {
        this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION); 
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
    }
}
```

Does anybody have a solution for this issue?

I tried the following:

I put in the manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

and used in `OnCreate`:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

And in both `onCreate()` as well as in `onResume()`:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
```

Still the titlebar is shown.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

add this in manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR"/>
```

inside onCreate()

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    View v = findViewById(R.id.home_view);
    v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
```

where home_view is the parent view of xml file.

```
 @Override
     public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            return false;
        }

 public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
     {
             try
             {
                if(!hasFocus)
                {
                     Object service  = getSystemService("statusbar");
                     Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
                     Method collapse = statusbarManager.getMethod("collapse");
                     collapse .setAccessible(true);
                     collapse .invoke(service);
                }
             }
             catch(Exception ex)
             {
             }
     }
```

you can't capture the home event, the only thing is you can do is to give your application home category and let the user choose.

```
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
```

Comment: Requiring a user to select what app to launch sucks.